# Generation of svg on server side using highcharts

Tags: node.js, svg, highcharts, jsdom

I did require('jsdom') in node js but i constantly get jsdom module not found.
More over i want to generate a svg document using highcharts on the server so that i can later on use that image in my pdf( I will convert that svg to image using batik).
Is there a link that may help me with this.
I have read through the http://blog.davidpadbury.com/2010/10/03/using-nodejs-to-render-js-charts-on-server/
but the prototype didnt make much sense. Is there a module which has been implemented rather than just a prototype.

Comment: Well, where did you install jsdom? And how?

Comment: I have fixed that jsdom issue. Thanks.
Please suggest me some solution for the second part of the question :( i have been struggling with it for a week now

Comment: I am using java as the server side language and i cant change that coz my company wont let me do it. So i have all the data with me. Through java i need to call node js server which will generate me the SVG using highcharts.js . How can i do that? The problem is solved once i get SVG coz using batik is pretty simple :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install all the required modules first. First download the tar file from his github https://github.com/davidpadbury/node-highcharts. Go to the directory where you saved the file and hit

`npm install davidpadbury-node-highcharts-576f763.tar.gz`

if you need to install additional modules like jsdom, try

`npm install jsdom`

His prototype seem to work fine with older version of highchart. but i am having some problem using it with latest highchart.

I hope this helped

Comment: did you ever have any luck with later highcharts? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: I gave up on using nodejs and used a java solution found here https://github.com/one2team/highcharts-serverside-export.
However this solution also had problems with the new highcharts so what i did was opened up the older highchart js file and replaced some of the methods from the newer highchart. Not a best solution and it seems to meet my needs for now.

Comment: github.com/one2team/highcharts-serverside-export is the one i used. This was far easier than using nodejs. Thanks all for the answers.